# Slide through page effect?

Tags: plugins

I would like my home page to jump to each section on scroll - kind of like a vertical slide show. This website is an example of what I am trying to achieve https://cornstudio.gr/.

Is there a WP plugin that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JS library you can use - [FullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#page1)

Here's the official [WordPress theme for FullPage.js](https://themify.me/themes/fullpane)

And [here's the plugin](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/wordpress-plugin-gutenberg/)